# IPython LaTeX math not rendered in HTML using nbconvert

Tags: latex, ipython, markdown

while trying to convert my ipynb to html I get no LaTeX math from the markdown cells rendered. The final HTML contains original LaTeX notation instead. The notebook renders well using the ipython web based editor, however the export to HTML not.

Do I do something wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Hmm, it seems a link to mathjax was broken in template (and so in the generated html), this fixes it: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/6395

Answer (score 1):

I'm expanding over @lukas's answer in that his link points to a page with pertinent info, but too much info. [This link here](https://github.com/minrk/ipython/commit/170baf3084149349b1175f1ffda184797aaf6741) is more to the point.

For the impatient, change all occurrences of 'c328740.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com' into 'cdn.mathjax.org', so:

```
ipython nbconvert --to html nb.ipynb nb.html
sed 's|c328740.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com|cdn.mathjax.org|g' nb.html > fixed.html
```

will do.

Comment: _[NbConvertApp] WARNING | pattern 'nb.ipynb' matched no files
[NbConvertApp] WARNING | pattern 'nb.html' matched no files
[NbConvertApp] WARNING | pattern 'sed' matched no files
[NbConvertApp] WARNING | pattern 's|c328740.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com|cdn.mathjax.org|g' matched no files
[NbConvertApp] WARNING | pattern 'nb.html' matched no files_.  


With windows 10, conda 3.19.1, ipython 4.1.1.

Comment: @bastaPasta: (i) The posted code is a two-line bash script, so everything including and after "sed" is not an argument of the ipython nbconvert, but a second command. (ii) The example only works "as is" for a notebook named "nb.ipynb", and produces a fixed html file named "fixed.html", and is supposed to be adapted as needed.